# Show that $R$ is an order relation in $\mathbb{R^2}$

Tags: proof-verification, relations, alternative-proof

In $\mathbb{R^2}$ consider the relation $R$ as: $(x,y)R(x',y') \Longleftrightarrow x\leq x' and\ y \leq y'$

show that $R$ is an order relation.

1) $ \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} \ (x,y)R(x,y) \implies x \leq x \ and \ y \leq y$

which is true because $x = x$ and $ y = y$ $ \implies $ $R$ is reflexive.

2)     $( \ (x,y)R(x',y') \implies x \leq x' \ and \  y' \leq y \ )$ and $( \ (x',y')R(x,y) \implies x \geq x' \ and \ y' \geq y \ )$

which implies $x = x'$ and $ y = y' $ $\implies$ $R$ is anti-symmetric

3) $( \ (x,y)R(x',y') \implies x \leq x' \ and \ y' \leq y \ )$ and $( \ (x',y')R(z,z') \implies x' \leq z \ and \ y' \leq z' \ )$ $\implies x \leq z \ and \ y \leq z'$

which implies that $R$ is transitive

So $R$ is an order relation.

is this answer correct ?

Comment: What is your question?  Are you wondering whether you are correct?

Comment: @Batominovski the post has a "proof-verification" tag so the answer is yes.

Comment: There should be a question in your text no matter what.  The proof-verification tag is sometimes used to ask about unclear points in certain proofs.  Don't let readers read your mind.

Comment: While I do feel like your proof would be better communicated with more words that would clarify some of the underlying details, the core logic is intact. I guess you could say that the proof is "right," it would just be easier to parse through with more actual explanation. Granted, this might be a personal thing. $R$ indeed does form an order relation, specifically a partial order.

Comment: At a glance you seem to have the right ideas, however you have written things in incorrect orders.  For reflexivity for example it should read "Suppose $(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2$.  Then since $x\leq x$ and $y\leq y$ is true it follows that $(x,y)R(x,y)$ and therefore $R$ is reflexive."  You instead *began* with what you wanted to prove (*or at least didn't make clear that this was the end goal rather than an assumption or a leap in logic*).

Comment: I found your logical use of $\implies$ arrows to be hard to interpret.